# R: Cumulative sum of X in ascending order of Y

Tags: r

would really appreciate some help. I am trying to produce a data frame with the cumulative sum of X, ordering on Y.

For example, if I have the following data frame df:

```
Y   X
1   1
3   4
2   2
4   7
5   8
```

I would want to produce:

```
Y   X   CumSumX
1   1   1
3   4   3
2   2   7
4   7   14
5   8   22
```

So:

```
df$CumSumX[1] ---> 1 (lowest value of Y)
df$CumSumX[2] ---> 1 + 2 (cumulative sum of X for 1st and 2nd lowest value of Y)
df$CumSumX[3] ---> 1 + 2 + 4 (cumulative sum of X for 1st, 2nd and 3rd lowest values of Y)
etc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
> transform(df, CumSumX=cumsum(df[order(df$Y), "X"]))
  Y X CumSumX
1 1 1       1
2 3 4       3
3 2 2       7
4 4 7      14
5 5 8      22
```

where `df` is your data.frame.

```
df$CumSumX <- cumsum(df[order(df$Y), "X"]) # this is another alternative
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I couldn't get it to work but ended up using the Lc function from the ineq package, which does what I wanted to do.